# Improving queries performance

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have a script that goes and queries a string from a field box.

Issue: This script takes too long! How can I improve the time to get results?

```
Set-Location master:
Get-ChildItem -Path "master:\\sitecore\content" -Language * -Recurse -Force | 
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        if ($_.InnerData.Fields | Where-Object {$_.value -match 'Dynamics CRM'}) {
            $_.Paths.FullPath | Write-Log 
        }             
    }
```

Comment: How many items are in your content tree? This would have to recurse through all of them, yes? If you have a lot of items, it's going to take a long time.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell given the above, you are trying to search the entire tree for instances of `Dynamics>CRM` and writing the path to a log, you might see some better times from a `fast://` query since it does not care about order given the tree compared to the `Get-ChildItem`:

```bsh
$query = "fast:/sitecore/content//*[@Field1 = 'Dynamics>CRM' or @Field2 = 'Dynamics>CRM']"
Get-Item -Path "master:" -Language * -Query $query | ForEach-Object { $_.Paths.FullPath | Write-Log }
```

You could also try and leverage your indexes:

```bsh
$root = (Get-Item "master:/sitecore/content/")
Find-Item -Index sitecore_master_index `
          -Criteria @{Filter = "DescendantOf"; Field = $root },
                    @{Filter = "Contains"; Field = "field1"; Value = "Dynamics>CRM"},
                    @{Filter = "Contains"; Field = "field2"; Value = "Dynamics>CRM"} |
    Initialize-Item | ForEach-Object {$_.Paths.FullPath | Write-Log }
```

I would say the only real deviation from my above scripts to what you provided is defining fields to search by compared to just searching all things everywhere.  That tidbit alone might help you speed things up.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I query a string from a text box (for example in Full Width Paragraph:  Script search for Dynamics CRM --- and in Full Width box there is a string containing  **Dynamics CRM**  - which will return the template Path. Is this possible?

Comment: What is the `Full Width box`, is it a field on an item? If so you should be able to swap out `Field1` for `Full Width box` or `field1` for `full_width_box` respectively in the snippets above. The output will be the item path, similar to your original post.

Answer (score 2):

A non-SPE approach is to use the out-of-the-box Search tab.

1. Select the `/sitecore/Content` item
2. Type in the search box `custom:` (tab)
3. Type `fieldname|Dynamics>CRM`
4. Search

It should return all items with a field of `fieldName` with a value of `Dynamics>CRM`. It has the added benefit of using the index by default, so it will be very quick. This doesn't write to the log, but perhaps that wasn't a requirement.

**Search And Replace**

From the search tab, you can also replace values.

[image: Search and Replace]

Type in the existing word (`Dynamics>CRM`) and the replacement.

[image: Replacement Word]